# Sending a mail as both HTML and Plain Text in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I'm sending mail from my C# Application, using the SmtpClient. Works great, but I have to decide if I want to send the mail as Plain Text or HTML. I wonder, is there a way to send both? I think that's called multipart.

I googled a bit, but most examples essentially did not use SmtpClient but composed the whole SMTP-Body themselves, which is a bit "scary", so I wonder if something is built in the .net Framework 3.0?

If not, is there any really well used/robust Third Party Library for sending e-Mails?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What you want to do is use the AlternateViews property on the MailMessage

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx

Answer (score 66):

The MSDN Documentation seems to miss one thing though, I had to set the content type manually, but otherwise, it works like a charm :-)

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(username, nu.email, subject, body);
msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
msg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlContent);
htmlView.ContentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");
msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Comment: +1 Cancelled out that down vote because this was useful to me.

Comment: It looks like the MSDN Documentation has been updated: the C# version of their example code uses a version of AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString that takes the content type as a parameter. The C++ version does not (they may have neglected to update it).

Comment: @jep I was able to prevent my smtp server (one similar to Exchange) from re-encoding the plain text version to BASE64 by using msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.ASCII.  The htmlView is unharmed.

Comment: So I should pass textual version of email in constructor ..?

Answer (score 36):

Just want to add that you can use defined constants `MediaTypeNames.Text.Html` and `MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain` instead of `"text/html"` and `"text/plain"`, which is always a preferable way. It's in `System.Net.Mime` namespace.

So in the example above, it would be:

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlContent, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
```

Comment: I would prefere: var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlContent, new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

Answer (score 11):

I'm just going to put a note here for anyone that's having problems and finds their way to this page - sometimes, Outlook SMTP servers will reconvert outgoing email.  If you're seeing your plain-text body vanish entirely, and nothing but base64-encoded attachments, it might be because your server is reencoding the email.  Google's SMTP server does not reencode email - try sending through there and see what happens.

Comment: I did indeed find my way here (over four years later) looking for that. Any chance you or anyone reading this know how to make it stop it on Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 SP3?

Comment: SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory is your friend for knowing exactly what is sent to the outgoing SMTP client.  Allows you to save a copy of the RAW email (open with notepad) sent by the .NET SmtpClient.

Answer (score 9):

On top of using AlternateViews views to add both the html and the plain text view, **make sure you are not also setting the body of the Mail Message** object.

```
// do not do this: 
var msg = new MailMessage(model.From, model.To);
msg.Body = compiledHtml;
```

As it will make your email contain the html content in both views, overriding the alternative views.

Answer (score 9):

For the people(like me) who've had the problem of gmail displaying the plaintext part instead of the html part.

Gmail seems to always display the last part in your message.

So if you've added the html part before your plain text part chances are gmail will always show the plain text variant.

To fix this you can simply add the plain text part before your html part.

Comment: This behavior is actually according to MIME specification rfc2046: 
"In this case, the alternatives appear in an order of increasing faithfulness to the original content.  In general, the best choice is the LAST part of a type supported by the recipient system's local environment."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who bumped into this issue you might want to check if you have preheader tags in your html.

In my html I've added a  tag with a phrase of "Activate your client admin account by clicking the link.".

It seems like gmail is flagging the phrase "clicking the link" after removing it, all my emails that has been sent, are going straight to the inbox.