# How to format an email that tells Outlook users to "view in HTML" if viewing in plain text mode?

Tags: html, asp.net, email, alternateview

Our client's computers all have Outlook configured to default reading emails to plain-text mode, but offer a relatively unnoticeable "View in HTML" button.  The users are relatively non-technical.  I want to include a note to anyone viewing the email in plain-text that they should click the "view in html" option to get proper hyperlinks and bulleted lists and such. Ideally that message would disappear when viewed in HTML.  I can send complete alternate views (a la [Sending a mail as both HTML and Plain Text in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44777/237091), we use .NET to send the emails) but I was wondering if there was a simple CSS (or similar) trick to do it, as I want the same message either way, just with an extra notification.

tl;dr: How do I send an email with some text seen only in plain-text mode, and the rest seen in HTML or plain-text mode?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this appears to work:

```
<p style='color:white;font-size:1px;margin:0;padding:0'>To use links in this
email in Outlook, you may have to click \"(i) This message was converted to 
plain text.\" above.</p>
```

It is essentially invisible while in HTML mode, but normal text in plain-text mode.