# MailMessage class

Tags: c#, string, email

I want to add an image into my mail, I have everything working for the most part but my only problem is that in order to have an image I need to set the body to HTML format... which then stops me from having break lines. So I think this is a 2 part question.

Is there a way to have both normal String for the first part of a message body and then the HTML for just the picture? or if not the How can I find and change the break line of a normal String to < br>?

I believe I need to change \n to < br/> in a normal String

```
body.Replace("\n", "< br/>);
```

doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I am assuming you are using the Mail Libray in .net ?

Comment: This should work. However, are you using the return value of the Replace method, ie. `body = body.Replace(...);`?

Comment: A MailMessage has a boolean IsBodyHtml, that is the prompt to you that an 'email' can only be one or the other. You can specify one or the other or both (plain text being an AlternateView), BUT only one will be displayed depending on what the client requests!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
body = body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

the mail format actually is written in the header of the message so its either TEXTformat or HTML format, you cant mix them both in the same message

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the Mail Libray in .net ? you will need to change your format type from text to HTML with the **IsBodyHtml** on the mail message

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a html image and use `AlternateView` to then get the plain text

[Sending a mail as both HTML and Plain Text in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44777/427684)