# MailMessage in .NET: why are the <br/> tags being inserted literally into my emails?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mailmessage

I have this email sending function:

```
''' <summary>
''' Sends an email.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="from">Who is the email coming from?</param>
''' <param name="to">Who is the email going to?</param>
''' <param name="subject">Subject of the email.</param>
''' <param name="body">Body text of the email.</param>
''' <returns>true if an email was sent, false if sending failed.</returns>
Public Shared Function SendEmail(ByVal from As String, ByVal [to] As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal body As String) As Boolean
    ' sanity check - can't send to nobody!
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace([to])
        Return False
    End If

    ' get http objects
    Dim http = HttpContext.Current
    Dim Request = http.Request
    Dim Session = http.Session
    Dim Response = http.Response

    ' find SMTP server
    Dim smtpServer As String
    If Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") = OverridableServerName Then
        smtpServer = LocalServerName
    Else
        smtpServer = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
    End If

    ' compose email
    Try
        Dim message As New MailMessage(from, [to], subject, body.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br/>"))
        message.IsBodyHtml = True
        Dim emailClient As New SmtpClient(smtpServer)
        emailClient.Send(message)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim uri = New Uri(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, UriKind.Relative).ToString()
        ' trim off the query string
        If (uri.IndexOf("?") >= 0)
            uri = uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?"))
        End If
        Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.asp?ErrorMsg=From " & uri & "<br><br>" & smtpServer & "<br>" & from & "<br>" & [to] & "<br>" & subject & "<br>" & Replace(body, vbCrLf, "<br>") & "<br>" & Replace(ex.Message, vbCrLf, "<br>"))
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The problem is that even though I am setting the `IsBodyHtml` flag to true, the `<br/>` tags that I am replacing newlines with get rendered literally rather than as newlines in the resulting email. is there a better way to do this? Should I not replace the newlines with `<br/>` tags? (I would test it out but I don't have a local email server, which is why I'm asking what to do here, so I don't have to keep throwing it over the fence into testing land just to see the resulting emails...)

Comment: Which client do you use to read the email? Is that client enabled to read the body as HTML or it is just TEXT for it?

Comment: Oh, that's a good question. It's not my email client reading these emails; it's someone else's. I guess I could test this by having some emails come to me...

Comment: Perhaps the client with the problem is reading as plain text. You can take that into account: [Sending a mail as both HTML and Plain Text in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44777/1115360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.IsBodyHtml = True` did actually fix it, even though I thought it didn't; we were just testing the wrong system when thinking it wasn't fixed. Oops!